# displaying live data what user insert into form

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make display value from live filling `form`. **For example**, selecting value from `dropdown select box`, then its showing me `ID`, but I wanted to display value which is DB table.

***Suppose,*** I select `field:NSE`while filling form, its should be live diaply "NSE" but its showed me `ID` as '1'

`exchange` table:
[image]

below is my code:

**JS:**

```
function all_function()
{
  value = $("#exchange").val();
  if (value != "") 
  {
    $("#exchange_value").html("Selected Exchanges :"+value);
  }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'trades\AddSingleTradeController@store', 'id'=> 'form', 'files'=>true]) !!}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::label('exchange_id', 'Exchanges:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('exchange_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $exchanges , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'exchange', 'name'=>'exchange_id',  'onchange' => 'all_function()'])!!}
  </div>
  <p id="exchange_value"></p>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: use like datatable with ajax sync

Comment: Can you guide me how to use `ajax sync`? @C2486

Comment: Please [start from here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: that is only `datatable` display, but i want to display live what user insert into `form`.

Comment: you want display the selected option in the table, right after user select the in form?

Comment: It will give live data if you search or any event done in datatable you can fetch current data, I could  use `setInterval` as `1000` to fetch record or you can add `refresh` button which fetch record after click.

Comment: yes you are right @DsRaj but not `id`.  I want to display data which in `table` of field name `exchange`

Comment: add the code of $exchanges from where you get the value for this variable?

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc_dinesh/rzwsn2tu/)

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati have you check this fiddle

Comment: yes i have checked @DsRaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**:

```js
 function all_function()
 {
    value = $("#exchange option:selected").text();
    if (value != "") 
    {
        $("#exchange_value").html("Selected Exchanges :"+value);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="exchange" id="exchange" onchange="all_function()">
    <option value="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2">def</option>
    <option value="3">ghi</option>
    <option value="4">jkl</option>
    <option value="5">mno</option>
</select>
<div id="exchange_value"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome @KinnariPrajapati